# Deploy vsix referenced dlls

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have a visual studio extension project which uses some external library. More over that library uses another library which must be placed in the same folder with the exe file. (in our case it is Visual Studio folder. Folder where Visual Studio was installed.) So how I can deploy my vsix file? Exists there any ability to copy some external libriries in the Visual Studio folder or not?

First idea is to copy library dll in the first of the extension. But it is not very nice...

Comment: Why "must" the library be placed with the same folder as the .exe? Is it a managed code DLL, where it's just important the DLL can be found in the probing path?

Comment: Yes, unfortunaly, it is managed dll.